# Render Partial View from Area in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial, area

I have a main MVC application wherein I have few Areas, for instance Sales and Marketing. These 2 areas are separated in 2 different MVC applications. Is it possible to render partial Views from these 2 areas into my main MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the full location of the view when rendering it Inside main view you can do like this

```
@Html.Partial("/Areas/User/Views/SomeController/Sales.ascx")
```

@Html.Partial("/Areas/User/Views/SomeController/Marketing.ascx")

Comment: Please try this.                                                                              @Html.Partial("/Areas/User/Views/SomeController/Sales.ascx")

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ActionView"); }
```

or:

```
@Html.Partial
```

Comment: 1. What is the difference between these two? 
2. I have created separated application for Area. So I need to load partial view from that application into my main application .